# How to obtain X & Y values of a projected point shapefile?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates

I know how to add X and Y coordinate values of a shapefile to the attribute table.

Now I would like to know how to achieve the coordinate values (in m) from a projected shapefile?

I am working with QGIS but I also have ArcGIS at my disposal.

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. QGIS will calculate the x and the y in the coordinate system of the file. So if you want it in a certain projection just reproject the file and calculate the x and the y.

Answer (score 2):

If you have re-projected your shapefile (meaning you have a second shapefile in another coordinate system and not displaying your original shapefile in another coordinate system with on the fly reprojection) then you just add the XY coordinate the usual way, the coordinate will be in the unit of the CRS (so if your shapefile is projected using a coordinate system that use meters as unit your corrdinate will be in meters).

If you dont reproject but use on the fly reprojection, the "calculate geometry" of ArcGis let you choose to use the shapefile coordinate system or the data frame coordinate system and also choose the unit. With QGIS you have to use the 'transform' fonction in the field calculator...